# Why is there no existing virtual environment in setting up Django?

Tags: python, django

I successfully installed Django but when I type the command *pipenv shell* I get an error

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pipenv.pew
```

so when i also type the command *pipenv --venv* it says:

```
No virtualenv has been created for this project yet!
```

I'd appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Why would installing django create a virtualenv?  They are are two separate things.  You have to create one yourself.

Comment: @JohnGordon I agree. A virtual env needs to be created.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to setup a new virtual environment? Looks like you do not have one setup yet at all. You need to establish one first.

**Try this:** https://www.javatpoint.com/django-virtual-environment-setup

For *VSCODE* I did it like this:

```
# macOS/Linux
# You may need to run sudo apt-get install python3-venv first
python3 -m venv .venv

# Windows
# You can also use py -3 -m venv .venv
python -m venv .venv

> Source - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
```

Please let me know if I am off with what your asking. Just trying to help. I have python virtual environment experience but no Django.